# Disabling carousel arrows on Bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

How do I how to disable bootstrap prev(next) arrow on first(last) slide. I'm working on a website and I can't find a way to disable the arrows on my carousel. I'm using bootstrap 5. There are tons of solutions for bootstrap 4 and below but I'm having a hard time converting it to its current version

Comment: possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25562053/stop-bootstrap-carousel-to-cycle-at-the-end-of-the-slide/25563266)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [options](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/#options), you can set the attribute `data-bs-wrap` to `false` :

```
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-wrap="false">
```